# Is there a way to show custom subtitles track name in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, avfoundation, http-live-streaming, subtitle, avplayerviewcontroller

`AVPlayerViewController` can perform a lot of work like switching audio/subtitles tracks, draw progress bar, retrieving thumbnails etc. On tvOS it automatically display builtin tracks in top bar and accept event from remote control. 
[image]

It recognize WebVTT subtitles and can display user selected track. But it doesn't work with SMPT-ETT/TTML subtitles. There is a way to manually decode and display subtitles of these formats. **But** is there a way to add a button with track language to a "Subtitles" chapter?

Comment: there is no code. I'm asking the question to a community

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new AVMediaSelectionOption of type AVMediaCharacteristicLegible and add it to AVAsset's mediaSelectionGroup(AVMediaSelectionGroup) and provide that asset to the AVPlayer it should show up in that list above the player.